# "logout" word on every program

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, logout

When I write every C++ program, such as that one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Tell me where to start: ";
    cin >> n;
    while (n>0) {
        cout << n << "\n";
        n = n-1;
    }
    cout << "FIRE!";
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with G++ and, when I run it, it works well, but when it finishes it displays the "logout" word after the program's last word, like this:

```
Tell me where to start: 10
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
FIRE!logout

[Process completed]
```

Why? And how can I remove it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not from your program. It's because the terminal is opened with the sole purpose of running your program, and as such when it exits, the terminal shuts down.

If you open a shell and manually run your executable, instead of this message, you'll simply get another command prompt.

Comment: I tried to `open` the file directly from the terminal but it opens a new window and it still displays the "logout" word

Comment: Just write its path instead of using `open`. You can do that by dragging the executable to the terminal window.

Comment: I positioned myself on the file's folder, but if I write the file's name it says `command not found`, so I think I should add the extension. What's the extension of a compiled C++ file? The properties window only tells me it's a terminal executable file

Comment: No, there is no extension, but you need to *prefix* the file with `./`, as in `./program`.

Comment: Unless you're using Windows, there is no extension on an executable program. If you can't just type the name of the command, then it's probably the case that the current directly isn't included in your search path — the `PATH` variable. To work around that temporarily, simply include some path segments when you run the program — for example, type `./prog` instead of just `prog`. To permanently allow yourself to run programs from whatever the current directory is, you should edit your startup file to add `.` to the `PATH` environment variable.